# How to show only one row in angular datatable?

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am new to angularjs, i have 25 rows to show, but for first time loading i am trying to show only one row, there will be one expand button to show remaining rows, then on click of expand i want to show all the rows.
Here is the code.

```
    <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
          <td>{{x}}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: what do you expand ? question is not clear

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati i want to show one row at first, there will be one expand button, on click of it i need to show remaining rows.

Comment: @user3932103 Working Plnkr code - http://plnkr.co/edit/HHBTE2wiEjI2z9PbEhBC?p=preview let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: @swapnesh i have four tds in tr, its not working with table row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names | limitTo: limit">
    <p>{{x}}</p>
</div>
```

$scope.limit = 1;

and on ng-click you can set your limit like: ng-click='limit = names.length'

Comment: if we want to show remaining elements on any expand button then?

Comment: @user3932103 I have modified the code for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can try.

```
<div ng-init="limit= 1">
    <button ng-click="limit=names.length">View</button>
    <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="x in names | limitTo: limit">
                <td>{{x}}</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alpeshprajapati/7MhLd/2252/

Comment: if it is key value pair, limitTo is not wokring, is there any other method?

Comment: can you show sample code ? m not able to understand

Answer (score 1):

Try [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter :

The `limitTo` filter returns an array or a string containing only a specified number of elements.

**Syntax :**

```
{{ object | limitTo : limit }}
```

As per the requirement :

**Js :**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.elements = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
  $scope.limit = 1;
});
```

**Html :**

```
<button ng-click="limit=elements.length">Expand More</button>
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in elements | limitTo: limit">
     <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Working fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/rohitjindal/vcxvvecr/2/

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Angular `slice` filter for arrays

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('slice', function() {
  return function(arr, start, end) {
    return arr.slice(start, end);
  };
});

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
$scope.offset = 1;
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]; 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='MainController' ng-init="start = 0;">
   
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items | slice:start:offset">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="offset = items.length">Expand</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I use slice for limit set

You can also try with:
**limitTo: (limit) : (begin)**

you can say ng-repeat="item in list | limitTo:50:0"

Answer (score 0):

Limit the rows by set a scope variable in the controller and filter it in the ng-repeat.

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('limitCtrl',function($scope) {    
  $scope.limitNumber = 1;
});
```

Html:

```
<table>
      <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="x in names | limitTo: limitNumber">
          <td>{{x}}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```